# How to process lines which is read from standard input in UNIX shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I get stuck by this problem:
I wrote a shell script and it gets a large file with many lines from stdin, that's how it is executed:

```
./script < filename
```

I want use the file as an input to another operation in the script, however I don't know how to store this file's name in a variable.
It is a script that takes a file from stdin as argument and then do awk operation in this file it self. Say if I write in script:

```
script:
#!/bin/sh
...
read file
...
awk '...' < "$file"
...
```

it only reads first line of the input file.
And I find a way to write like this:

```
Min=-1
while read line; do
    n=$(echo $line | awk -F$delim '{print NF}')   
    if [ $Min -eq -1 ] || [ $n -lt $Min ];then
    Min=$n
    fi
done
```

it would take very very long time to wait for processing, it seems awk takes much time.
So how to improve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I finally find this way to solve my problem, although it will take several seconds.

```
grep '.*' >> /tmp/tmpfile
Min=$(awk -F$delim 'NF < min || min == "" { min = NF };END {printmin}'</tmp/tmpfile)
```

Just append each line into a temporary file so that after reading from stdin, the tmpfile is the same as input file.

Answer (score 2):

You're overdoing this.  The way you invoke your script:

- the file contents are the script's standard input
- the script receives no argument

But `awk` already takes input from stdin by default, so all you need to do to make this work is:

- not give `awk` any file name argument, it's going to be the wrapping shell's stdin automatically
- not consume any of that input before the wrapping script reaches the `awk` part.  Specifically: no `read`

If that's all there is to your script, it reduces to the `awk` invocation, so you might consider doing away with it altogether and just call `awk` directly. Or make your script directly an `awk` one instead of a `sh` one.

Aside: the reason your `while read line`/multiple `awk` variant (the one in the question) is slow is because it spawns an `awk` process for each and every line of the input, and process spawning is order of magnitudes slower than `awk` processing a single line.  The reason why the generate tmpfile/single `awk` variant (the one in your answer) is still a bit slow is because it's generating the tmpfile line by line, reopening to append every time.

Comment: Thank you! But it seems you misunderstand my question, I need to write a script that takes a file from stdin as argument and then do awk operation in this file it self. I only know read line.

Comment: @Alex Oh, ok, I (think I) get it now. But then as I read it, it's your question's preconceptions that are flawed. If you call your script as `./script < filename`, it's not going to transmit the file name to the script, only the file contents. Which makes it surprising that the awk invocation inside the script gets to see the first line of the file at all: in optimal conditions all it can see is the (full) contents of a file whose name is in the first line of the input file, instead of the firect first line of contents of the input file. You ought to clear that bit up.

Comment: Oh I see, it's my fault. But do you know how to catch the file read from stdin? If ./Script filename, then I just need to use file=$1 so as to give awk as argument. I need to use awk inside script.

Comment: If all your process *is* that awk program, it already takes stdin by default. All you need to do is 1) not specify any input and 2) not consume it elsewhere in the wrapping script (e.g. with `read`). I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/stdin` can be quite useful here.
In fact, it's just a chain of links to your input.

So, writing `cat /dev/stdin` will give you all input from your file and you can deny using input filename at all.

Now answer to question :) Recursively read links, beginning at `/dev/stdin`, and you will get filename. Bash code:

```
r(){
    l=`readlink $1`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo $1
    else
        r $l
    fi
}
filename=`r /dev/stdin`
echo $filename
```

UPD:
in Ubuntu I found an option `-f` to readlink. i.e. `readlink -f /dev/stdin` gives the same output. This option may absent in some systems.

UPD2:tests (test.sh is code above):

```
$ ./test.sh <input # that is a file
/home/sfedorov/input
$ ./test.sh <<EOF
> line
> EOF
/tmp/sh-thd-214216298213
$ echo 1 | ./test.sh 
pipe:[91219]
$ readlink -f /dev/stdin < input 
/home/sfedorov/input
$ readlink -f /dev/stdin << EOF
> line
> EOF
/tmp/sh-thd-3423766239895 (deleted)
$ echo 1 | readlink -f /dev/stdin
/proc/18489/fd/pipe:[92382]
```

Comment: Hi, because file is read from stdin just like : ./script < filename, thus there is no $1 you can access in script file, that's what makes me annoying...

Comment: `$1` here is the argument to the `r` function, not a script argument. `/dev/stdin` is the argument passed to `r`, which by recursive calls to `r` eventually leads you to the name of the file which was redirected to standard input.

Comment: I tried, but echo $filename just print fd/0, when execute to awk '...' < "$filename", it throw "fd/0: No such file or directory"

Comment: try to run like this: ./test.sh < input

Comment: I updated answer with run examples. What is exact command you running? What is OS?

Comment: I try to read a file with multiple lines and each lines have distinct number of words or say columns separated by comma. I wanna use script to calculate the minimum number of columns. In fact I found I can write "while read line;do ... done" to process each line and find the minimum, however if I write "n=$(echo $line | awk -F$delim '{print NF}')" inside to hold each line's num of column, it takes very long time to wait due to large input file.     My OS is mac, I do it in shell.

Comment: 1. try to use awk with all input, not with every line.
I tried this: (does the same that your code)
Min=$(awk -F$delim '{print NF}'| sort -n | head -n 1)
for file with ~100 lines, it took less than 1 second.
2. As I thought, this question was about getting filename by stdin. If you need to discuss awk performance problems, here should be another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script to that it takes the input file name as an argument, then read from the file in your script:

```
$ ./script filename
```

In `script`:

```
filename=$1
awk '...' < "$filename"
```

If your script just reads from standard input, there is no guarantee that there *is* a named file providing the input; it could just as easily be reading from a pipe or a network socket.

Comment: actually I need to implement two ways to get argument, your version is ok and I already implemented, so I just wonder how to use stdin.

Answer (score 0):

How about invoking the script differently pipe standard output of YourFilename into
your scriptName as follows (the standard output of the cat filename now becomes standard
input to you script, actually in this case to the awk command
For I have filename Names.data and script showNames.sh execute as follows

cat Names.data | ./showNames.sh

Contents of filename Names.data
Huckleberry Finn
Jack Spratt
Humpty Dumpty

Contents of scrip;t showNames.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#whatever awk commands you need
awk  "{ print }"
```